# How can I get events for all NFC types?

Tags: java, android, nfc

I currently have an app where the user has to log in to use it. In the near future we might support an NFC chip to log in without entering a username and password. I have absolutely no idea scanning an NFC chip works so I looked up some tutorials and found [this one](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/reading-nfc-tags-with-android/).

I copied the code from the tutorial and I think I understand how it works. The problem is that it does not work for the card I have to test with (the onNewIntent method is not called, as opposed to what the tutorial is telling me). The card works (other apps pick it up just fine), so I guess the problem is that it is a different type than the one used in the tutorial. So I changed the xml mentioned in the tutorial into the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.Ndef</tech>
    </tech-list>
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.IsoDep</tech>
    </tech-list>
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcA</tech>
    </tech-list>
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcB</tech>
    </tech-list>
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcF</tech>
    </tech-list>
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcV</tech>
    </tech-list>
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.Ndef</tech>
    </tech-list>
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NdefFormatable</tech>
    </tech-list>
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.MifareClassic</tech>
    </tech-list>
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.MifareUltralight</tech>
    </tech-list>
</resources>
```

This is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="nl.boomerweb.nfc"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.nfc"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="nl.boomerweb.nfc.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"
                android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I assumed this would scan not only for the Ndef type of chip, but also for all the others. But my app still does not respond when I hold the card to the phone.

These are the card details I retrieved by using an NFC scanner app:

**RF Technology:**
Type A (ISO/IEC 14443 TYPE A)

**Tag Type:**
Mifare Classic 1K

**ATQA:**
0004

**SAK:**
08

**Target technology classes (Android):**

```
android.nfc.tech.MifareClassic,  
android.nfc.tech.NfcA,  
android.nfc.tech.NdefFormatable
```

I'm testing on a Samsung Galaxy SIII, with android 4.1.2. I have enabled nfc and sBeam on the device and another app that scans nfc chips works perfectly, so the problem must be in my code. I created a separate project to test this, which only contains the code as seen in the final part of the tutorial mentioned above (so just the MainActivity, the manifest and nfc_tech_filter.xml).

The best would be a solution that can read all cards, but for now something that can read this card would be fine. I would also appreciate it if someone could explain how adding a new type of nfc chip works. We will probably support more than one type after this one works.

Comment: What intent filters do you use in your manifest? Also, do you want the application to launch upon scanning a tag or do you just want to receive tag discovery events while your app is visible?

Comment: @MichaelRoland I added the manifest file code to the question. I want to get the event of scanning a tag when the app is open or closed, it should not matter. Is it possible to register for both situations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution that works for me. There were actually two problems with the tutorial, one was that my app did not respond to the card at all, the other came after I solved the first one and that was that the app was re-opened when it was already running. This is all the code I used to solve both problems:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.nfc"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.nfc"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.nfc.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
                android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"
                android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED"
                android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**nfc_tech_filter.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.Ndef</tech>
    </tech-list>
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.IsoDep</tech>
    </tech-list>
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcA</tech>
    </tech-list>
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcB</tech>
    </tech-list>
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcF</tech>
    </tech-list>
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcV</tech>
    </tech-list>
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.Ndef</tech>
    </tech-list>
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NdefFormatable</tech>
    </tech-list>
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.MifareClassic</tech>
    </tech-list>
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.MifareUltralight</tech>
    </tech-list>
</resources>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.nfc;

import android.nfc.NfcAdapter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String MIME_TEXT_PLAIN = "text/plain";
    public static final String TAG = "NfcDemo";
    private NfcAdapter mNfcAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
        if (mNfcAdapter == null) {
            // Stop here, we definitely need NFC
            Toast.makeText(this, "Dit apparaat ondersteund geen NFC.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
            return;
        }
        if (!mNfcAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "NFC staat niet aan", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        handleIntent(getIntent());
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setupForegroundDispatch(this, mNfcAdapter);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        stopForegroundDispatch(this, mNfcAdapter);
        super.onPause();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        handleIntent(intent);
    }
    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null && intent.getAction().contains("android.nfc")) {
            //if we are here, we captured an nfc event
        }
    }
    public static void setupForegroundDispatch(final Activity activity, NfcAdapter adapter) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(activity.getApplicationContext(), activity.getClass());
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

        final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(activity.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);

        String[][] techList = new String[][]{};
        adapter.enableForegroundDispatch(activity, pendingIntent, null, techList);
    }
    public static void stopForegroundDispatch(final Activity activity, NfcAdapter adapter) {
        adapter.disableForegroundDispatch(activity);
    }
}
```

As you might see I have added all possible actions to the manifest. To make sure the foreground dispatch works I removed the filters from the tutorial. This will of course give problems when more events are fired but I figured I can always filter them later on. Not the most elegant solution, but it gets the job done.

Comment: Note that the `<meta-data ...>` section is only applicable for the `TECH_DISCOVERED` intent filter, so you should remove that section for `NDEF_DISCOVERED` and `TAG_DISCOVERED`. Also, you can remove the `<action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />` intent filter, as it won't trigger due to missing data/category section. Moreover, you should avoid the `TAG_DISCOVERED` intent filter as it is only meant as a fall-back mechanism.

Comment: @MichaelRoland Thanks for your tips. I'll be sure to take a look at it when my holiday is over.